# using try-catch to catch gpio interrupts

Tags: gpio, python, interrupts, sockets

Is it possible to interrupt a try-except code in python with gpio interrupt to generate exception?
In the "try" part i'm openning a socket and use socket.serve_forever().
I want to make a hard-reboot to the program, using a reboot button that is connected to a gpio.
What I want is that when button is pressed-an interrupt/exception is invoked and it goes right to the "except" part (going out of an infinite loop) , closing the socket and restart the program (later openning the socket again).

Example for code:

```
try:
    ... #code
    socket.serve_forever
except GPIO INTERRUPT:
    print "button was pressed, closing socket and restart program..."
    socket.close()
    restart()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best you can do is use a gpio event callback to set a shutdown flag and have your socket loop act on the flag when it is seen.

If the socket loop may not be entered for some time then you will have to find an action which triggers a socket message.

Alternatively use your gpio event callback to force a restart itself.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/), it explains how GPIO Interruptions works

You can modulate interruption like that:

```
GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.RISING)
do_something()
if GPIO.event_detected(channel):
    print('Button pressed')here
```

You'll be able to break a loop or call a function !